# Google spreadsheet publish to web for specific user

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

How to publish excel spreadsheet to web page for view only specific user?

When i'm trying to share spreadsheet, able to manage people and access level.
(Share link)https://docs.google.com/a/domain.com/spreadsheets/d/key-id/**edit?usp=sharing**

But there is no option when trying to publish to web with specific user.
(Publish link)https://docs.google.com/a/domain.com/spreadsheets/d/key-id/**pubhtml?gid=0&single=true**

Is there any other option to publish to web with specific user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to restrict who can open a ***published*** spreadsheet.  (As opposed to a ***SHARED*** sheet file) You could have everything in the Sheet hidden by default; create an `onOpen()` function that checked who the current user was, and then if it's an approved user, show all the sheets, and if it's not an approved user, hide and protect all the sheets.    If there were multiple users, the last saved version probably wouldn't be the version with all the sheets hidden, so I don't know how that would work with multiple users.

There is no method to close a Sheet.  If there was, you could close the sheet if it was the wrong user.

You could create a HTML Web App with a Sheet embedded into it with an iFrame HTML tag.  Then require anyone who went to the URL of the Web App to log in, or they would be stuck at a blank log in page.

Comment: Thanks sandy, Please let me know is there any other way to push specific link for specific user. Yes im working for multiple user and i can able to restrict view only for my domain user. But i can't able to restrict for specific user.

Comment: And also if i got solution to push specific link for specific user its over!

Comment: Not possible. Publishing means to all always. Write a webapp instead that displays the data only to that user, its the only way.